# emacs isearch-forward default search string

Tags: emacs, elisp

I have a question about Emacs Lisp, I want to achieve this functionality: ‘highlight a word under cursor, then when I push C-s C-s, I can jump to the next highlighted word’.
So after I highlight a word, I hope the **isearch-string** can be set as the same as the word I have high lightened, i.e. the **default ** search string for command **isearch-forward** or **isearch-backward** can be my highlighted word.

My code is like:

```lisp
(defun highlight-current-word()  
  "highlight the word under cursor"
  (interactive)
  (let (head-point tail-point word) 
    (skip-chars-forward "-_A-Za-z0-9")
    (setq tail-point (point))   
    (skip-chars-backward "-_A-Za-z0-9")
    (setq head-point (point))
    (setq word (buffer-substring-no-properties head-point tail-point))
    (setq isearch-string word)      ; no use
    (isearch-search-and-update) ; no use
    (highlight-regexp word 'hi-yellow)))
```

But it always prompts: [No previous search string]
Can you help me? Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried `C-s C-w`?  This should auto-highlight the current word (or multiple words for more `C-w`) and highlight the same search string as you move forward (or backward) with `C-s` (`C-r`)...

Comment: I concur with abiessu, but you can also simply your own code if you obtain the word with `(thing-at-pt 'word)` (or `bounds-of-thing-at-point` if you still need to remove properties manually).

Comment: ah, i just want to know what variable controls the default isearch string

Comment: That would be `search-ring`

Comment: @juanleon, thank you very much!! search-ring works :)

Comment: @juanleon, do you know is there any 'highlight-regexp-ring' kind of thing to store highlighted word history?

Comment: I don't think so (there is `regexp-search-ring`, but that has nothing to do with highlighting)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need add hook to isearch-mode, then your function will be work.

```
(defun highlight-current-word()
  "highlight the word under cursor"
  (interactive)
  (let (head-point tail-point word)
    (skip-chars-forward "-_A-Za-z0-9")
    (setq tail-point (point))
    (skip-chars-backward "-_A-Za-z0-9")
    (setq head-point (point))
    (setq word (buffer-substring-no-properties head-point tail-point))
    (setq isearch-string word)
    (isearch-search-and-update)))

(add-hook 'isearch-mode-hook 'highlight-current-word)
```

Comment: but this makes your normal C-s fail, you need search on space area or M-n/p  to search other words

Answer (score 2):

Is this all you are looking for (not too clear to me)?

```
(defun foo ()
  (interactive)
  (skip-chars-backward "-_A-Za-z0-9")
  (isearch-yank-internal (lambda () (forward-word 1) (point))))

(define-key isearch-mode-map (kbd "C-o") 'foo)
```

That does what `C-w` does, except that it picks up the whole word at the cursor, not just the text from the cursor to word end.